# jsf selectonemenu error

Tags: jsf

Hi: 
I am developing a jsf project, I am having touble with getting selectOneMenu to work.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeEditBean.employeeBean}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{employeeEditBean.branchList}" />
     </h:selectOneMenu>
public class EmployeeEditHandler
{
 private String paramEmPK;
 private Employee employeeBean;
 private List<Branch> branchList;

 private int branchFK;


 public EmployeeEditHandler()
 {
  paramEmPK = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getRequestParameterMap().get("emPK");
  int emPK = Integer.parseInt(paramEmPK);
  branchList = new ArrayList<Branch>();
  employeeBean = new Employee();
  FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
  try 
  {
   employeeBean = DaoFactory.getEmployeeDao().lookupEmployeeByPK(emPK);
   branchFK = employeeBean.getBranchFK();
   branchList = DaoFactory.getBranchDao().findAllBranch();

  } 
  catch (Exception e) {
   FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(e.getMessage());
   msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
   context.addMessage("employeeEditForm", msg);
  }
 }
```

> The error is:javax.servlet.ServletException: Argument Error: An option for component j_id8 was not an instance of javax.faces.model.SelectItem.  Type found: java.util.ArrayList.
>    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)
>    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
>    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
>    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
>    org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your `employeeEditBean.branchList` to be of type `List<SelectItem>`, where each `SelectItem` has a value (the string that will be transferred as a post parameter) and a label.

So you'd need to create that list based on your original branch list.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, i found another way to do this. I add a tomahawk12 library.

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{employeeEditBean.branchFK}">
    <t:selectItems value="#{employeeEditBean.branchList }" var="br" itemLabel="#{br.branchName}" itemValue="#{br.branchPK }" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

I did not change code in employeeEditBean.

Thanks all